# How get get data in descending order using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query and I want the data in descending order according to totalPopulation.

```
var query = from u in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "DetailedUtility")
            select new
            {
                UtilityId = (int)u.Attribute("UtilityId"),
                TotalPopulation = u.Elements(ns + "City")
                                   .Sum(c => (int)c.Attribute("Population"))
            };
```

How can I get the list in descending order.
Please help

Comment: @Coelho, that question looks to be more about troubleshooting an error than about how to achieve descending order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var query = (from u in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "DetailedUtility")
            select new
            {
                UtilityId = (int)u.Attribute("UtilityId"),
                TotalPopulation = u.Elements(ns + "City")
                                   .Sum(c => (int)c.Attribute("Population"))
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPopulation);
```

or

```
var query = from u in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "DetailedUtility")
            let population = u.Elements(ns + "City")
                              .Sum(c => (int)c.Attribute("Population"))
            orderby population descending
            select new
            {
                UtilityId = (int)u.Attribute("UtilityId"),
                TotalPopulation = population
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from u in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "DetailedUtility")
            select new
            {
                UtilityId = (int)u.Attribute("UtilityId"),
                TotalPopulation = u.Elements(ns + "City")
                                   .Sum(c => (int)c.Attribute("Population"))
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPopulation);
```

Comment: Ha looks like @MarchinJuraszek beat me to it. Oh well.